# Whoosh library Percentage of matching searcher.search

Tags: python, whoosh

## Im trying to check how much does the query matches the search

Here is the full code:

```
import tempfile
from whoosh import index
from whoosh.fields import Schema, TEXT, ID
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser

def most_similar_key(string, dictionary):
    """Finds the most similar key to the given string in the given dictionary."""
    most_similar_key = None
    global most_similar_score
    most_similar_score = 0

    schema = Schema(key=ID(stored=True), text=TEXT(stored=True))

    # Create an in-memory directory for the index
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        ix = index.create_in(temp_dir, schema)
        with ix.writer() as writer:
            for key in dictionary:
                writer.add_document(key=key, text=dictionary[key])

        with ix.searcher() as searcher:
            query_parser = QueryParser("text", schema=schema)
            query = query_parser.parse(string)
            results = searcher.search(query)
            if len(results) > 0:
                most_similar_key = results[0]['key']
                most_similar_score = results[0].score

    return most_similar_key, most_similar_score

def print_value_to_key(string, dictionary):
    """Prints the value to the key that is most similar to the given string."""
    key, score = most_similar_key(string, dictionary)
    if key is not None:
        value = dictionary[key]
        similarity_percentage = score * 100
        print(f"{key}: {value} ({similarity_percentage:.2f}%)")
    else:
        print("No similar key found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dictionary = {
        'go to playstore, download a game, find it on home screen, click on it and start playing' : 'how to play games',
        'in the sea' : 'where are the fish',
        'its yellow' : 'what is the color of the sun'
    }
    string = "how to play games"
    print_value_to_key(string, dictionary)
```

The problem is that the score is above 1 so when it gets multiplied by 100 it gives off percentage
Im new to Whoosh so i dont know what to do

Ive actually not really tried anything since I dont really understand the code